# libgdx borderless fullscreen

Tags: java, libgdx, screen

I try to give the user the option of how he wants to play the game. Window and Fullscreen Mode is no problem. The thing I don't seem to get to work is the borderless fullscreen/windowed fullscreen.
I searched the web and found only one site that helped me:

http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13863

I did as I was told and I think it kinda works, my problem is, the windows 10 toolbar at the bottom is always in front of the window.
Here the picture of how it looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch6Kx.jpg

The color is awful, but just for testing purposes. Code looks like this:

```
if (screenManager.FULLSCREEN) {
    Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().width, Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().height, true);
} else if (screenManager.WINDOWEDFULLSCREEN) {
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");
    Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().width,
    Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().height, false);
} else {
    Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(screenManager.WIDTH, screenManager.HEIGTH, false);
}
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**
I updated to 1.9.2, which doesn't has the setDisplayMode method.
The code now looks like this:

```
DisplayMode mode = Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode();
if (screenManager.FULLSCREEN) {
    Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode().width, Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode().height);
    Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(mode);
} else if (screenManager.WINDOWEDFULLSCREEN) {
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");
    Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode().width, Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode().height);
    //Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(mode);
} else {
    Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(screenManager.WIDTH, screenManager.HEIGTH);
}
```

Everything works like before, just the borderless fullscreen has the windows toolbar(the thing on the botton) infront of it, just like in the picture. Normal fullscreen works fine.

Comment: Are you looking to remove the border of a windowed application? If so then you might want to try asking "How to remove border from windowed application". Since now you are confusing a lot of people with the clutter in your question. Please be specific when you are asking questions and leave all irrelevant stuff out of it.

Comment: @MennoGouw the code actually allready removes the border ...

Answer (score 5):

Just tested the following config on my machine with Windows 10 and it worked:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.width = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().width;
        config.height = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().height;
        config.fullscreen = true;
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), config);
    }
}
```

You should set that in `DesktopLauncher` in desktop module

**UPDATE**
You should try:

```
Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode());
```

Also, what version of LibGDX are you using? I'm on version 1.8.0 and I don't have `Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode()` method.

Comment: If i do it like this, the game will allways be fullscreen. But the user should be able choose  from fullscreen, windowed fullscreen and window mode ...

Comment: I got 1.6.0, the fullscreen mode works, i just have problems with windowed fullscreen, i hope you know what i mean...

Comment: it also is clear why the toolbar is infront, i just set the display mode as a window and removed the frame, but how can i put the window infront of everything. Just like all modern games do now a days ?

Comment: It's seems to me that it't just Windows feature that a toolbar is always in front of opened apps. I just tested with "Life is Strange" game and if I set there windowed full-screen mode the toolbar is in front too. Unfortunately, I don't have any other games to test.